# Openshift SSH permission denied through corporate proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, ubuntu-14.04, openshift-online-2

am trying to connect local->cntlm->company proxy->rhcloud host.

I have the keys uploaded to rhcloud and GitHub. With the current configuration with corkscrew i am able to connect to git via ssh. However ssh -v to host doesn't work.

The fingerprint is same when I check with ssh key-gen list in local and rhc show-app list for Openshift.

Here is the trace.

```
ubuntu@satubuntu:~/.ssh$ ssh -v user@host.rhcloud.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for user@host.rhcloud.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /usr/bin/corkscrew 127.0.0.1 3128 user@host.rhcloud.com 22
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1000
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA cf:ee:77:cb:0e:fc:02:d7:72:7e:ae:80:c0:90:88:a7
debug1: Host 'user@host.rhcloud.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Any pointers on why public key is denied?

config under .ssh has

```
Host appname-domain.rhcloud.com
User user
Port 22
Hostname appname-domain.rhcloud.com
IdentityFile "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa"
TCPKeepAlive yes
IdentitiesOnly yes
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/corkscrew 127.0.0.1 3128 %h %p

Host github.com
User git
Port 22
Hostname github.com
IdentityFile "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa"
TCPKeepAlive yes
IdentitiesOnly yes
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/corkscrew 127.0.0.1 3128 %h %p

Host ssh.github.com
User git
Port 443
Hostname ssh.github.com
IdentityFile "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa"
TCPKeepAlive yes
IdentitiesOnly yes
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/corkscrew 127.0.0.1 3128 %h %p
```

Comment: The log says `debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa` but that's normally the **private** key. What's in your `~/.ssh/config`?

Comment: Please add it to your question, it's unreadable in a comment.

Comment: Shouldn't Host user@host.rhcloud.com be: Host host.rhcloud.com

Comment: Updated config in the right way.

Comment: Use `rhc ssh` to ssh to your gear.

Comment: ubuntu@satubuntu:~$ rhc ssh -a donor
Connecting to user@app-domain.rhcloud.com ...
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).